# После цикла for первая строка, не связанная с циклом, не переводится вниз, а пишется правее, почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Естественно, я могу написать `print("\n")`, но у меня возник вопрос - почему строка "Также нужно купить 10 кг риса" пишется не снизу, а правее?

```
My_shopping_list = ["Apple" , "Samsung" , "Gucci" , "Walmart"]
print("Покупки : " , end = " ")
for i in My_shopping_list:
    print(i , end = " ")

print("Также нужно купить 10 кг риса")
```

https://www.online-python.com/s40elXQWbY

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. как создать [mcve].

Comment: Код бы хорошо.
И в чём задача, - ещё лучше.

Comment: `end = " "` — а это вы откуда скопипастили? И понимаете ли вы зачем оно тут?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in My_shopping_list:
    print(i , end = " ")
```

Вам тут не нужно использовать `end = " "` если вы не хотите, чтобы дальше печать шла без перевода строки.
А если вы хотели разделить пробелом печатаемые элементы, то нужно было использовать не окончание пробел, а разделитель пробел `sep = " "` и печатать список без цикла:

```
print(*My_shopping_list, sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `end=' '`, следовательно после каждого вывода будет не перенос строки, а просто пробел. Вот у вас и нет переноса строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
My_shopping_list = ["Apple" , "Samsung" , "Gucci" , "Walmart"]
print("Покупки : " , end = " ")
for i in My_shopping_list:
    print(i , end = " ")
print()

print("Также нужно купить 10 кг риса")
```

end - параметр не обязательный, он в пустом принте по умолчанию, поэтому достаточно пустого принта будет